# Passing the last node with data to the output XML (XSLT question)

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml:

```
<peci:Address>
    <peci:Country>seq0</peci:Country>
</peci:Address>
<peci:Address>
    <peci:Country>seq2</peci:Country>
</peci:Address>
<peci:Address>
    <peci:Country></peci:Country>
</peci:Address>
```

Using the following XSLT line (sheet and template data is extensive so I've decided not to include it):

```
xsl:value-of select="peci:Address/peci:Country"/>
```

Gets me the following data:

```
<cell name="Country">seq0 seq2 </cell>
```

Whereas I would like:

```
<cell name="Country">seq2</cell>
```

`[last()]` would produce `<cell name="Country"/>` so that is not what I'm looking for.

It would have to be scalable because there may be more or less than 3 Country nodes, some of which may be blank. I simply want the last instance of them all.

Eg:

```
<peci:Address>
    <peci:Country>seq0</peci:Country>
</peci:Address>
<peci:Address>
    <peci:Country>seq2</peci:Country>
</peci:Address>
<peci:Address>
    <peci:Country></peci:Country>
</peci:Address>
<peci:Address>
    <peci:Country>seq3</peci:Country>
</peci:Address>
```

Should be:

```
<cell name="Country">seq3</cell>
```

If you could provide some ideas, that would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a predicate `(peci:Address/peci:Country[normalize-space()])[last()]`.